# rewrite_rules wordpress URL

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to rewrite an URL

from: `http://localhost/hockey-oefening/70/interceptie-warming-up`

to: `http://localhost/hockey-oefening/?oefening=70&naam=interceptie-warming-up`

I tried to add manually .htaccess file. However, I did not get it to work. So I reset the .htaccess file and looked for another way.

Then I added the following code in my functions.php

```
function custom_rewrite_rule() {
    add_rewrite_tag('%oefening%', '([^&]+)');
    add_rewrite_tag('%naam%', '([^&]+)');
    add_rewrite_rule('^hockey-oefening/([^/]*)/([^/]*)?', 'index.php?page_id=563&oefening=$matches[1]&naam=$matches[2]', 'top' );
}
add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_rule', 10, 2);
```

This adds a rule to the $wp_rewrite array as I can see with

```
global $wp_rewrite;
print_r($wp_rewrite);
```

The output:

```
   [extra_rules_top] => Array
    (
        [^wp-json/?$] => index.php?rest_route=/
        [^wp-json/(.*)?] => index.php?rest_route=/$matches[1]
        [^index.php/wp-json/?$] => index.php?rest_route=/
        [^index.php/wp-json/(.*)?] => index.php?rest_route=/$matches[1]
        [service/?$] => index.php?post_type=services
        [service/feed/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$] => index.php?post_type=services&feed=$matches[1]
        [service/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$] => index.php?post_type=services&feed=$matches[1]
        [service/page/([0-9]{1,})/?$] => index.php?post_type=services&paged=$matches[1]
        [^hockey-oefening/([^/]*)/([^/]*)?] => index.php?page_id=563&oefening=$matches[1]&naam=$matches[2]
    )
```

Now when I try to go to `http://localhost/hockey-oefening/70/interceptie-warming-up`, I get a redirection to `http://localhost/registreren/`

Now I was thinking that my page_id might be wrong, but the hockey-oefening page has id: 563 and the register page id: 11.

Answer (score 0):

Try this following code

```
add_filter('query_vars', 'parameter_queryvars' );
function parameter_queryvars( $qvars )
{
  $qvars[] = 'oefening';
  $qvars[] = 'naam';
  return $qvars;
}


//rewrite part
function wpse120653_init() {    
    add_rewrite_rule(
        'hockey-oefening(/([^/]+))?(/([^/]+))?/?',
        'index.php?pagename=hockey-oefening&oefening=$matches[2]&naam=$matches[4]',
        'top'       
    );
}   
add_action( 'init', 'wpse120653_init' );
```

Hope it works

Comment: Thank you for your reply! It's not working yet. With the code you wrote I'm getting redirected from `http://localhost/hockey-oefeningen/` to the register page. To clarify a couple of things I have this page `http://localhost/hockey-oefeningen` which is an overview of the oefeningen (exercises) and then I have a different page `http://localhost/hockey-oefening/?oefening=71&naam=partijvorm-half-veld` which accepts the parameters 'oefening' and 'naam'. I want that link to be `http://localhost/hockey-oefening/71/partijvorm-half-veld` but most of the time with what I try I get redirected to registe

Comment: have you save the permalink after add this code? i try on my local site it's worked

Comment: Yes I did that. No results

Comment: do you have both pages ( exercises & excercise) , I'm not sure why it's not worked.. I always use this code for many sites and never found any error

Comment: I have both pages yes. Oke thank you. I also don't know where to look for.